# How to set default values for daterange widget in baseFieldDefinitions

Tags: forms, entities, datetime

Everything is working in my code except the default values...

```
$rangedefaults['value'] = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time());
$rangedefaults['end_value'] = DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time());

$fields['date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('daterange')
  ->setLabel(t('Date and time'))
  ->setDescription(t('When the activity takes place.'))
  ->setRequired(false)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'daterange_default',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setDefaultValue($rangedefaults);
```

What is the proper way to set default values for this widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just the date format. If you look at the `DateRangeItem` class's `generateSample` method, it uses the [`DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21datetime%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21DateTimeItemInterface.php/constant/DateTimeItemInterface%3A%3ADATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT/8.5.x) format to prepare both `value` and `end_value`. You probably just need to do the same:

```
$rangedefaults['value'] = $rangedefaults['end_value'] = (new DrupalDateTime())->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
```

As an aside, since you're using the current time it feels like you might want the default value to be the time at which the entity is created. By setting it in the field definition, the default will always be the time you installed the field.

That might be what you want, but in case not, use `setDefaultValueCallback` instead, and add a method to the entity class which returns the default value.

Comment: You are correct.  I need to use setDefaultValueCallback.  I am finding this works: ->setDefaultValueCallback('Drupal\my_entity\Entity\MyEntity::getDaterangeDefault');  ...and then the callback... static public function getDaterangeDefault() {
    $obj = new DrupalDateTime();
    $now = $obj->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
    return $now;
  }

Comment: My callback needed a tweak or two: static public function getDaterangeDefault() {
    $obj = new DrupalDateTime();
    $now = $obj->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
  
    $val = substr($now, 0, -5) . '00:00';
    return array('value' => $val, 'end_value' => $val);
  }